# Object doesn't support property or method 'mediaelementplayer'

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to add the video tag and apply [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) to it.

If I do this, it works correctly (reduced the Video tag for brevity, but doesn't throw any error):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/mediaelementplayer.min.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/mediaelement-and-player.min.js'></script>
<video width='640' height='320' id='MEWP'>
</video>
<script>$('MEWP').mediaelementplayer()</script>
```

But, if I add the tag through code, .mediaelementplayer() throws     **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'mediaelementplayer'**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/mediaelementplayer.min.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/_layouts/MediaElementWebPart/mediaelement-and-player.min.js'></script>
<div id="videosContainer">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
        var id = "MEWP-" + random.toString();
        var video = "<video width=\'640\' height=\'320\' id=\'" + id + "\' ></video>";
        $(video).appendTo('#videosContainer');
        $('#' + id).mediaelementplayer();
    });
</script>
```

The video tag's element seems to be found though, per the debugger

```
[+]     $('#' + id)[0]  {...}   [Object, HTMLVideoElement]
```

What am I missing here? Any general advice for troubleshoot these kind of things, appreciated.

Comment: Is there a 404 on the media element js? Try the non-minified version

Comment: There is an error in first script hiding another error
<script>$('#MEWP').mediaelementplayer()</script>. Add # to make it id-selector.

Comment: In which browser version do you test? The message looks like IE

Comment: Rob - .js and .css both work, no 404.// Yury - '#' is already there, '#' + id, where am I missing the '#'? //Bergi - correct, IE9

Comment: Found the issue... yet another JS lesson learned: there was a jquery.js reference already in the master page. I took it out, and no more errors. Tricky one to discover, only after started playing with the network capture and removing includes to start small... Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: <script>$('MEWP').mediaelementplayer()</script> 
I bet $('MEWP').length === 0 :)

Comment: Yury, length was 1, truly. The question to me comes now... how to manage the fact that different components may be including jQuery.js on their own? For ex. in C you avoid doble #include's with #DEFINE, any equivalent here? Thanks!

Comment: @Ariel would you mind post your comment as answer, so that we can better upvote it, and the question actually has an answer?